# Exposing dict values via properties

Tags: python

I have this (Py2.7.2):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dict_values):
        self.values = dict_values
        self.changed_values = {} #this should track changes done to the values{}
        ....
```

I can use it like this:

```
var = MyClass()
var.values['age'] = 21
var.changed_values['age'] = 21
```

But I want to use it like this:

```
var.age = 21
print var.changed_values #prints {'age':21}
```

I suspect I can use properties to do that, but how?

**UPDATE:**

I don't know the dict contents at the design time. It will be known at run-time only. And it will likely to be not empty

Comment: What use is `changed_values`? When does it differ from `values`? What does that afford you?

Comment: Simple - I want to see what exactly was changed. Yes, it can be replaced with a list of keys, but that is not the point of the question.

Comment: I mean, how does looking at the keys of `values` does not work for you? Are items ever removed from `changed_values` and do the values in `changed_values` ever change from the current values in `values`?

Comment: Looking at the keys of `values` just tells me a certain key is there. But I need to know if it's value was changed.

Comment: `values` starts out empty, so every key which is present was changed (at least from not existing to existing) at least once. At least your example indicates that introducing a key also counts as changing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17140/discussion-between-delnan-and-alexvhr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that inherits from a dict and override the needed functions

```
class D(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.changed_values = {}
        self.__initialized = True

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.changed_values[key] = value
        super(D, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        """Maps values to attributes.
        Only called if there *isn't* an attribute with this name
        """
        try:
            return self.__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(item)

    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        """Maps attributes to values.
        Only if we are initialised
        """
        if not self.__dict__.has_key('_D__initialized'):  # this test allows attributes to be set in the __init__ method
            return dict.__setattr__(self, item, value)
        elif self.__dict__.has_key(item):       # any normal attributes are handled normally
            dict.__setattr__(self, item, value)
        else:
            self.__setitem__(item, value)

a = D()
a['hi']  = 'hello'
print a.hi
print a.changed_values

a.hi = 'wow'
print a.hi
print a.changed_values

a.test = 'test1'
print a.test
print a.changed_values
```

output

```
>>hello
>>{'hi': 'hello'}
>>wow
>>{'hi': 'wow'}
>>test1
>>{'hi': 'wow', 'test': 'test1'}
```

Comment: That looks very interesting, thanks. I wonder if it can be simplified in light of the updated part of the question, however.

Comment: using this implementation, you can either change the dict content as usual (like in the first example) or by using a parameter (like in the third example). So it doesn't really matter when or where you update the dict content

Comment: by the way, if you want to have some kind of a log of the changed items, I would recommend using a list of tuples where each tuple is a pair (key, value). This way, if a value changes twice, you can see it. Also, there are no limits to the data you can put on that structure, like the time, the old value (Good for an undo/redo feature) ...

Answer (score 0):

Properties (descriptors, really) will only help if the set of attributes to monitor is bounded. Simply file the new value away in the `__set__()` method of the descriptor.

If the set of attributes is arbitrary or unbounded then you will need to overrive `MyClass.__setattr__()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `property()` built-in function.

This is preferred to overriding `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, as explained [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#property).

```
  class MyClass:  

      def __init__(self):
          self.values = {}
          self.changed_values = {}

      def set_age( nr ):
           self.values['age'] = nr
           self.changed_values['age'] = nr

      def get_age():
           return self.values['age']

      age = property(get_age,set_age)
```

Comment: But in this case I have to write "static" getters and setters. What I want to do is to create them dynamically.